# How to make sense of National Instruments Publish Subscribe Protocol?

Tags: protocols, labview, distributed-system, plc

I am trying to speak to a compactRio device by National Instruments. My goal is to read and write data to the compactRio device. I've figured out that it is running something called National Instruments Publish Subscribe Protocol which happens to be proprietary. Wireshark is only able to figure out that it is running on top of TCP. Has anyone here tried reverse engineering the protocol? How should I go about doing that?

I'm currently thinking of trying to send a request that changes a certain value, with different values to figure out what changes in the packet but the problem is that the front-panel keeps exchanging messages with the system so spotting these packets that I want to send would be tough. Should I go on with this method of finding out what changes just to get my work done?

Comment: I think this question is either too broad ("tell me how to reverse-engineer a protocol") or off-topic ("point me to a resource explaining this protocol") - not sure which is more (in)appropriate.

Comment: it's more of the latter but i was aiming at people who tried to reverse engineer the protocol but never wrote about there experience. as i couldn't find much literature online.

Answer (score 0):

There is an interface [available](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/372636F-01/mstudiowebhelp/html/6cadafd0/), but you'll need to know what is available. You have to setup the cRIO application with the data you want to provide.

Comment: Nice find :). I'll check this out, I even found something called NetworkVariableWriter.I'll push an update when I get something running or if I hit a dead end that I can't pass. New to C#, but that shouldn't be a problem!